# tensorflow cifar10 example Learning rate decay confusion when using multiple gpus

Tags: python, tensorflow

community,
I have a small question about the learning rate decay in multi-GPUs training of the Tensorflow [cifar10](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py) example.

Here is the code:

```
# Create a variable to count the number of train() calls. This equals the
# number of batches processed * FLAGS.num_gpus.
global_step = tf.get_variable(
    'global_step', [],
    initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)

# Calculate the learning rate schedule.
num_batches_per_epoch = (cifar10.NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN /
                         FLAGS.batch_size)
decay_steps = int(num_batches_per_epoch * cifar10.NUM_EPOCHS_PER_DECAY)
# Decay the learning rate exponentially based on the number of steps.
lr = tf.train.exponential_decay(cifar10.INITIAL_LEARNING_RATE,
                                global_step,
                                decay_steps,
                                cifar10.LEARNING_RATE_DECAY_FACTOR,
                                staircase=True)
```

In this code, the number of gpus is not considered. For instance, if we increase the FLAGS.num_gpus to 4. The decay_steps does not change.

In the comments, global_step is supposed to equal the number of batches processed * FlAGS.num_gpus. However, global_step only increases when opt.apply_gradients() function is called. It only increases 1 step per iteration.

In my opinion, the code should be

```
decay_steps = int(num_batches_per_epoch * cifar10.NUM_EPOCHS_PER_DECAY/FLAGS.num_gpus)
```

Therefore, when utilizing multiple GPUs, the number of iteration required to go through 1 epoch is reduced.

Please correct me and help me understand if my logic is not correct.